How to access db in testcontainers from external client
I have a standard SpringBoot JPA project with PostgreSQL database. For integration tests I use testcontainers. Everything works fine but if some test fails I'd like run it in debug mode with an appropriate breakpoint and investigate what is the database state - what tables, records in tables and so on it has preferably with psql client working from terminal. My base test looks like
public class TestContainersExampleIT {

    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(
            "postgres:14-alpine"
    );

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        postgres.withInitScript("schema.sql");
        postgres.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() {
        postgres.stop();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void configureProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("datasource.kedr.postgres.jdbcUrl", postgres::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("datasource.kedr.postgres.username", postgres::getUsername);
        registry.add("datasource.kedr.postgres.password", postgres::getPassword);
    }

    @Test
    void exampleTest() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

}


The question is how can I connect to this database with psql client ?
I put break point at System.out.println() and run test in debug mode. It stops at break point and database seems running. At this moment I try to connect to it as

psql -h localhost -U test -d test

and got
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

What I do wrong? Please help. Thank you in advance

Are you trying to connect to the container while the program is stopped at the breakpoint? Or when the program is done? If done, then your @AfterAll has stopped it.

@CaptainChaos program stops at break point, at that moment db is running, it completed initial script schema.sql and can be resumed after break point. I know that db in testcontainers works during tests only. But external connection fails when db is definitly running

Connection refused suggests maybe problem with the user / PW. Perhaps print out the URL / username / PW when spinning it up and compare.

Another possibility is that the testcontainer doesn't have an exposed port linked to your computer's port.

Hmm, may be, but application connects to it somehow... Oh, yes, I missed the port in psql command, @CaptainChaos thank you very much!

Did that work? I hope you don't mind but I will write it up as an answer to your question, could you mark it as the solutions?

yes, sure, I don't mind

Connection refused suggests maybe problem with the user / PW. Perhaps print out the URL / username / PW when spinning it up and compare.
Another possibility is that the testcontainer doesn't have an exposed port linked to your computer's port.

It turns to be that db port in testcontainer is 32789 and should be used in psql instead of 5432
